# I just added a unit test for project PTable(PreetyTable) which works directly but failed with nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

Project source is here: https://github.com/kxxoling/PTable/tree/develop

I added a new test file `test_utils` into tests dir. When I move it out of that dir(because of importation) I can run the unit tests direct.

It is said that there is no error with my tests. But something goes wrong when I run all the tests together with nose: `nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=prettytable --cover-min-percentage=75` will get an error:

```
TypeError: _() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Very strange. My test file is like this:

```
import unittest
from prettytable.prettytable import _char_block_width

fixtures = {
    'normal': (1, u'12345qwerljk/.,WESD'),
    'chs': (2, u'石室诗士施氏嗜狮誓食十狮'),
    'jp': (2, u'はじめまして'),
    'hangul': (2, u'우리글자언문청'),
    'full_width_latin': (2, u'ＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿ｘｙｚ｛｜｝～｟'),
}

def _width_test_factory(width, words):
    def _(self):
        map(lambda x: self.assertEqual(width, _char_block_width(ord(x))),
            list(words))
    return _


class CharBlockWidthTest(unittest.TestCase):
    pass

for name in fixtures:
    test_name = 'test_%s' % name
    test_func = _width_test_factory(*fixtures[name])
    test_func.__name__ = test_name
    print test_func
    setattr(CharBlockWidthTest, test_name, test_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `_(self)` can only be executed inside the context of a class instance (which will supply the implicit parameter `self`. Not when nose is importing the modules and parsing them to find test functions.

The "nose-way" would be to simply move the test functions into the `CharBlockWidthTest` class. The three-layered composite function which is added to the class dynamically with `setattr` is simply a bit too complex for the testcase discovery mechanism.

I believe the following code should be a nose-friendly equivalent (not tested).

```
class CharBlockWidthTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_fixtures(self):
        for name, val in fixtures.items():
            width, words = val
            for x in words:
                self.assertEqual(width, _char_block_width(ord(x)),
                                 "Error on fixture %s: word %s" % \
                                 (name, word))
```

Comment: But I think it's better to split the fixture into several different test functions which seems more distinct. Any idea about that?

Comment: The most important factor in unit test is that it runs upon each update of the software, and a failure will direct you quickly to the problem. For that matter you can use either a loop with a proper error message or a series of separate test functions. Separate functions (including setUp and tearDown on each one) seems a bit heavy for this purpose, but it remains a matter of taste.

Comment: Could you give me a suggest how to split it to multi tests just as a technical problem?

Comment: You will probably end up with something like `test_ficture_chs(self)` etc. I do wonder what the added value would be.

Comment: Arabic, Hebrew, Mandarin, for the computer they're all unicode. If you use python 3, unicode is the native encoding for strings. In python 2 you must be explicit (`u"my unicode string"`).

Comment: Technically, do you have any idea to add test methods dynamically, and supports nosetests? I don't understand why it works stands alone, but fails with nosetests.

Comment: It's probably possible if you fiddle around with the testcase factory long enough so the nose's discovery mechanism will understand it. The question is, why is dynamic test function generation important? If I look at your current implementation, it's not the test function/assertion but the test content which looks dynamic. You can use dynamic content in a static `TestCase` as well (i.e. read from csv/json/...).

Comment: Yes, I've already choosing your solution in my code. But it's really confusing about the testcase discovering of nose.